# How can I draw multiple JLabels in different places? (icons don't show up)

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon

I am trying to draw multiple icons in many different locations using `for` loop. For some reason they just don't show up. I don't know what I'm missing – only clue I found was about setting layout to null, but IntelliJ overwrites it.
Icons should show up in "mapa" panel. I tried adding them manually, but nothing changed.

My code:

```java
package okna;

import logistyka.Walker;
import logistyka.errand.Errand;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class WalkerGUI extends JFrame{
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JLabel walkerName;
    private  JTextField walkerNameField;
    private JLabel walkerAddress;
    private  JTextField walkerAddressField;
    private JButton searchErrandsButton;
    private JComboBox errandsComboBox;
    private JLabel errandsList;
    private JTextField walletValue;
    private JLabel Wallet;
    private JRadioButton archivalErrandsRadioButton;
    private JRadioButton currentErrandsRadioButton;
    private JButton payOutButton;
    private JButton seeProfileButton;
    private JPanel mapa;
    ArrayList<Errand> masterErrandList = new ArrayList<>();

    public WalkerGUI(Walker w, ArrayList<Errand> masterErrandList)  {
        setContentPane(mainPanel);
        ArrayList<JLabel> errandsLabels = new ArrayList<>();
        ImageIcon x = new ImageIcon(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\src\\x.png");
        this.masterErrandList = masterErrandList;
        for (Errand errand: masterErrandList) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel("whtvr");
            label.setIcon(x);
            label.setLocation((int)errand.getAddress().getX(),(int)errand.getAddress().getY());
            label.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(20,20));
            label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,20));
            label.setVisible(true);
            errandsLabels.add(label);
        }

        walkerNameField.setText(w.getDescription().getName());
        walkerAddressField.setText(w.getDescription().getHomeRegion().getCurrentAddress().toString());
        walletValue.setText(String.valueOf(w.getWalletSatus()));
        seeProfileButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFrame frame = new ProfileGUI(w);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        payOutButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                w.setWalletSatus(0);
                walletValue.setText(String.valueOf(w.getWalletSatus()));
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: You are adding the labels to an `ArrayList`.  You need to add them to a JComponent like a `JPanel`.  Then add the JPanel to your JFrame before you `pack()` it and make it visible.

Comment: See: [How to Use Labels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) for complete working examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SpringLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html) (rather than null layout). Method `Errand.getAddress().getX()` will return the distance of the left edge of the `JLabel` from the left edge of its container while `Errand.getAddress().getY()` will return the distance of the top edge of the `JLabel` from the top edge of its container.

The code in your question is not a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so the below code should be considered as a [proof of concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_concept).

```java
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Point;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;

public class SprinGui {

    private void createAndDisplayGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Spring");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel contentPane = (JPanel) frame.getContentPane();
        SpringLayout layout = new SpringLayout();
        contentPane.setLayout(layout);
        Point[] points = new Point[]{new Point(5, 5),
                                     new Point(5, 100),
                                     new Point(225, 150),
                                     new Point(250, 210)};
        Class<?> meClass = getClass();
        Icon[] icons = new Icon[4];
        icons[0] = new ImageIcon(meClass.getResource("coffee.png"));
        icons[1] = new ImageIcon(meClass.getResource("dollar.png"));
        icons[2] = new ImageIcon(meClass.getResource("dynamite.png"));
        icons[3] = new ImageIcon(meClass.getResource("soccer-player.png"));
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            JLabel label = new JLabel(icons[i]);
            contentPane.add(label);
            layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST,
                                 label,
                                 points[i].x,
                                 SpringLayout.WEST,
                                 contentPane);
            layout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH,
                                 label,
                                 points[i].y,
                                 SpringLayout.NORTH,
                                 contentPane);
        }
        frame.setSize(450, 300);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SprinGui instance = new SprinGui();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> instance.createAndDisplayGui());
    }
}
```

This is how the GUI looks.

[image: screen capture]

Note that [How to Use Icons](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) may also be helpful.